# More Concise Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I have a big report that contains the chunk of text below:

```
$S Cal V1
1   1.000       353.2   20.0    47
2   4.000       179.4   19.9    95
3   8.000       -51.5   20.0    35
```

What I'm trying to get are three separate expressions to pull out the numbers in the second column.  The header ($S Cal V1) will stay the same but all of the numbers except the ones in the first column are subject to change.

This is the mess I have currently.  I know if can be condensed down but I was hoping for something cleverer as well.

```
\$S Cal V1\n1\s*(\d+\.\d+)
\$S Cal V1\n1\s*\d+\.\d+\s*\d+\.\d+\s\d+\.\d+\s*\d+\n2\s*(\d+\.\d+)
\$S Cal V1\n1\s*\d+\.\d+\s*\d+\.\d+\s\d+\.\d+\s*\d+\n2\s*\d+\.\d+\s*\d+\.\d+\s\d+\.\d+\s*\d+\n3\s*(\d+\.\d+)
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Just use the last expression, and put capture groups around the 2nd number in each row. Then you can get all 3 numbers at once.

Comment: What tool/language are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately I need to have three separate expressions for the software I'm using.  It is a piece of laboratory software that captures information from instruments.

Answer (score 1):

it appears the precision of the data is regular.

[use](https://regex101.com/r/JugpZs/1):  `\d\.\d{3}  //cleverer :)`